# Sagemaker endpoint error : Received client error (400) from primary with message "Data type passed in the request is wrong for one or more columns"

Tags: pyspark, amazon-sagemaker

Code sample

```
import json

schema = {
    "input": [
        {"name": "Year", "type": "integer"},
        {"name": "Engine HP", "type": "integer"},
        {"name": "Engine Cylinders", "type": "integer"},
        {"name": "Number of Doors", "type": "integer"},
        {"name": "highway MPG", "type": "integer"},
        {"name": "city mpg", "type": "integer"},
        {"name": "Popularity", "type": "integer"},
    ],
    "output": {"name": "feature_outputs", "type": "double"},
}


schema_json = json.dumps(schema)
print(schema_json)
from time import gmtime, strftime
import time

timestamp_prefix = strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())

import sagemaker
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
from sagemaker.sparkml.model import SparkMLModel


role ="sagemaker-execution-role"# get_execution_role()


sparkml_data = "s3://{}/{}/{}".format(
    "emr-spark-sagemaker", "emr/sparkml-layer/mleap", "model.tar.gz"
)
model_name = "sparkml-layer-" + timestamp_prefix

boto3_session = boto3.session.Session()
sagemaker_client = boto3.client("sagemaker")
sagemaker_runtime_client = boto3.client("sagemaker-runtime")


session = sagemaker.Session(
    boto_session=boto3_session,
    sagemaker_client=sagemaker_client,
    sagemaker_runtime_client=sagemaker_runtime_client,
)
sparkml_model = SparkMLModel(
    model_data=sparkml_data,
    role=role,
    spark_version="3.3",
    sagemaker_session=session,
    name=model_name,
    env={"SAGEMAKER_SPARKML_SCHEMA": schema_json},
)


endpoint_name = "sparkml-layer-ep-ap18"


sparkml_model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1, instance_type="ml.t2.medium", endpoint_name=endpoint_name
)


input_payload = {
    "schema": {
        "input": [
        {"name": "Year", "type": "integer"},
        {"name": "Engine HP", "type": "integer"},
        {"name": "Engine Cylinders", "type": "integer"},
        {"name": "Number of Doors", "type": "integer"},
        {"name": "highway MPG", "type": "integer"},
        {"name": "city mpg", "type": "integer"},
        {"name": "Popularity", "type": "integer"},
        ],
        "output": {"name": "feature_outputs", "type": "double"},
    },
    "data": [2019,330,6,4,50,40,300],
}

predictor = Predictor(
    endpoint_name=endpoint_name, sagemaker_session=session, serializer=JSONSerializer()
)
print(predictor.predict(input_payload))
```

This is the error i encountered while doing prediction:
Error:
An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message "Data type passed in the request is wrong for one or more columns"

I checked in cloudwatch for endpoint, but it don't specify which column is causing issues.